# Ubuntu 16.04 periodically resets /lib/systemd/system/memcached.service file

Tags: 16.04, systemd, memcached

I have installed memached on Ubuntu 16.04 and configured in `/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service` system service to use a custom config `/etc/memcached_server1.conf` file

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/memcached.service
[Unit]
Description=memcached daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/systemd-memcached-wrapper  /etc/memcached_server1.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see I'm using custom `/etc/memcached_server1.conf` file in the `ExecStart` section

After a while or because of some unknown action, `/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service` file resets to default `/etc/memcached.conf` config file ...

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/memcached.service
[Unit]
Description=memcached daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/systemd-memcached-wrapper  /etc/memcached.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To reproduce replacement I tried server reboot, systemctl restart memcached, systemctl daemon-reload but they are all useless. Nothing changes config to default one.

**Question:** What can cause replacement of `/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service` to default (after installation) one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't found any solution here and as best workaround decided to make `/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service` **none writable for anyone !**